# How do you create a logon trigger in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

I've never used Triggers before, but need to use one to capture a location based on the IPAddress on login.  I'm unsure of the structure and have followed guidance that was forwarded to me, but I cannot get it to work.  This is what I have at the moment -

```
CREATE TRIGGER LGNCC_TRIGLOG
ON LGNCC_LOGIN 
AFTER INSERT
AS
    declare @userid VARCHAR(10)
    declare @ipaddress VARCHAR(100)
    declare @lastactivity   VARCHAR(35)
BEGIN
    select 
        @userid = I.userid, 
        @ipaddress = I.ipaddress, 
        @lastactivity = I.lastactivity
    from 
        LGNCC_LOGIN I

   IF (@lastactivity = 'login')
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO lgnco_agent_location2(user_id, user_ip, user_location, user_date, User_Time)
          SELECT 
              @userid, @ipaddress, 'This is a test' as Location,
              LEFT (CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE),10) AS USERDATEIN,
             LEFT (CAST (GETDATE() AS TIME), 8) AS USERTIMEIN
   END
END
```

I've tried a number of different ways of compiling this, but nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: What error are you getting from the posted code?

Comment: The above doesn't populate lgnco_agent_location2, but as I'm relying on a structure that was supplied to me and know nothing about triggers, I don't know if the above is simply wrong or what I'm tryng to achieve is not possible.  So I guess the question is, is the above correct?

Comment: No errors, simply does nothing.

Comment: There are some challenges as I see it here. You are using scalar variables from the LGNCC_LOGIN table. Are there multiple rows in that table? Do you know that the ONLY value in the table for lastactivity is 'login'?? I suspect that your variable has some other value and the insert doesn't happen. The biggest issue I see is that this is an insert trigger and you do not reference the inserted virtual table anywhere. What exactly are you trying to do??? Also, your question title asks about logon triggers...this is NOT a logon trigger.

Comment: I get the feeling I might have been given some duff information in creating this, the problem with not having looked at triggers before.  There are multiple rows in the LGNCC_LOGIN table.  There are 5 other values possible for lastactivity and I get the feeling that I might have to start this one again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You trigger is executed after some data is inserted in the table `LGNCC_TRIGLOG`.

The insert is probably done from an application.

In that case the trigger can done as

```
CREATE TRIGGER LGNCC_TRIGLOG
ON LGNCC_LOGIN 
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO lgnco_agent_location2([user_id], user_ip, user_location
                                  , user_date, User_Time)
  SELECT userid, ipaddress, 'This is a test' as Location
       , LEFT (CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE), 10) AS USERDATEIN
       , LEFT (CAST (GETDATE() AS TIME), 8) AS USERTIMEIN
  FROM   Inserted
  WHERE  lastactivity = 'login'
END
```

`Inserted` is a special table, it is a copy of the trigger table that contains only the rows affected by the last `INSERT` or `UPDATE` executed.

If the column `User_Date` and `User_Time` in the table `lgnco_agent_location2` are of type `Date` and `Time` remove the `LEFT`, as is it useless.

Comment: Perfect.  that has worked a treat.  And many thanks for the explanation.  I had been told about Inserted, but it was not properly explained and ended up being replaced with my many attempts to get this to work.  Many thanks.